# Окончания в словах ПЛОЩАДЬЮ и ВОРОБЬЮ

Tags: фонетика, склонение, окончания

Какое окончание в словах:

> площадью (творительный)

и

> воробью (дательный)

?

Если смотреть фонетически, то окончание, как мне кажется, -jу. А в орфографической записи как?

Answer (score 2):

Воробей - воробь[й/у], звук Й входит в корень слова,

площадь - площадь/[йу], звук Й относится к окончанию

Answer (score 2):

> Если смотреть фонетически, то окончание, как мне кажется, -jу. **А в
>   орфографической записи как?**

У  ***площади*** звука [й’] нет ни в одном из падежей, кроме творительного. Значит, в творительном падеже этот звук принадлежит окончанию.  Окончание в ***площадью*** -- [й’у], или, что то же самое, -- ***ю.***

У ***воробья*** же звук [й’] прослеживается во всех падежах. Значит, этот звук относится к основе. Тогда окончание у ***воробью*** -- [у]. Можно ли по-иному обозначить это окончание?

Из Литневской (http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm#3_4 ):

> Чтобы не загромождать написание транскрипционными скобками, в
>   лингвистике принято обозначать звук [й’], «спрятанный» в йотированной
>   гласной букве, при помощи j, без скобок вписываемого в нужное место:
>   *статьj-ями*.

С учётом этого замечания можно так показать окончание в словоформе ***воробью***:

***воробьj-ю.***

Comment: В уверены, что это правильно: воробьj-ю. Получается, что звук Й назван два раза, да еще входит в окончание, хотя должен относиться к основе.

Comment: Но ведь такую  запись не я же придумал! См. у Литневской: **"в лингвистике принято..."**

Comment: А я смотрю в Морфемно-словообразовательном словаре РАН (для 5-11 классов), 2009 год, там другое оформление. Как-то у них там, в лингвистике, всё неоднозначно.

Comment: @Vera Просьба указать авторов книги, чтобы можно было найти её и посмотреть.

Comment: Да авторов-то и я могу указать (у меня этот словарь есть): Попова Т.В. и Зайкова Е.С. Только Вас-то интересовала ОРФОГРАФИЧЕСКАЯ запись окончания, её я и привёл в своём ответе.  Попова же и Зайкова используют для обозначения окончания фонетическую транскрипцию. К примеру, слово приморье разделено в этом словаре на морфемы так:
**при + морь + [й + (э)]**. Т. е. окончание -- [э].

Answer (score 0):

В орфографической записи всё просто: Ю-окончание -  площадь/ю, воробь/ю

В фонетической окончание -у : Воробей - воробь[j/у],  [j] входит в корень слова.

Площадь - площадь/[j/у], [j]-cуффикс, у-окончание

Раньше, лет 15 назад, разбирали так:

вороб/ей/нулев. оконч.,

воробь/[j/у]  , т.е. ей- и й - суффиксы.

Comment: Если верить Тихонову, то в слове *воробей* нулевое окончание. Я также склоняюсь к этой версии больше.

Comment: С этим и сейчас никто не спорит. Речь о корне Сейчас-воробей, а раньше-вороб-, а ей- суфф.   Это я к тому, что  в слове "площадью" - j- тоже суфф ., просто в "воробей" он слился с корнем, а в "площадью" нет.